# What is all this about? (photo of several small cup-like structures on top of Perseverance)

Tags: identify-this-object, rovers, perseverance

[image]

I have been trying to figure out what this arrangement is for.

Could it be where the mast had its 'face' buried prior to deployment?

The various cups seem to fit exactly with lenses and positioning lugs on the masts face. If so the visible cutter must have severed a hold down cable.

Am I on the right track?

Comment: That looks like one of those pyrotechnic release mechanisms too (shown [here](https://www.flickr.com/photos/planetaryblog/7490132802/) from [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/50287/12102))

Comment: thanks for the title edit uhoh....after studying many pics of the mast face and that cup-like arrangement.it all fits together perfectly.....does anyone agree ?

Comment: First thing that came to mind: Geee, those are going to fill with water if it rains. Next thing that came to mind: This is Nasa, they surely have that one figured out. :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Lens covers and attachment/deployment infrastructure for the camera mast.

The mast hosts 2 round Navcams on the sides, two rectangular Mastcam-Z cameras, and one large Supercam with half-circle top "archway-like" border.

[image]

Compare: The image taken using the [3D model](https://mars.nasa.gov/mars2020/spacecraft/rover/) from NASA site, mirrored by me so that the correspondence is obvious.

[image]

During descent the mast was tucked in. It seems like one of the [pyrotechnic cutters](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/50268/103) was used to ensure it would be released.

[image]

Comment: Pyrotechnic cutters?  Does that mean humans are *already* littering on another planet?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket And what do you think happened to the heatshield, the parachute and the skycrane?

Comment: Ya, I figured those were large enough that they will be *easy pickins* for Musk to grab when he's (hopefully) living up there.  But with all this smaller trash, he's going to be a busy boy having to clean up all this mess.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket I mean, Alan Shepard's golf balls have been lying around on the moon for decades.  Along with a bunch of other junk we left up there.  So we have a long history of littering other celestial bodies...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman When I quickly read your comment, I missed the word *golf*.  Quite a different meaning... and a good chuckle.

Comment: Apollo left whole cars in ditches on the Moon and IIRC even dumped their poo.

Comment: @Michael And you haven't even mentioned the nuclear waste yet.

Comment: Don't worry, @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket, the Jawas will pick up all of the debris and sell it to moisture farmers.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket The heatshield hits the surface at something not far from the speed of sound. The skycrane - AFAIK they don't try to land it gently, just fly it a good distance and altitude away and let it drop out of the sky. So I wouldn't count on them remaining single big chunks, with no debris strewn all around.

Comment: @SF I can't wait for a space agency to find something in a few years and think it's evidence of ET, only to realize it's a piece of litter dumped by Earthlings.

Comment: On the subject of debris, there are amazing pics on the NASA site taken 16 years ago by Opportunity when the rover visited the impact site of its heat shield.